# PHP : sending reset password link in email

Tags: php, html, css, email

I am sending password reset link using html email in php. This is structure of my code. First is html email:

```
<?php $bodymessage= '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >;
 $bodoymessaage= .='<a href="$link"' .....?>
```

then I've setup heaeders

```
 <?php $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 ?>
```

and after this i recieve form fields and mail function like this

```
if($passreset){
       mail($to, $subject, $bodymessage, $headers);
}
```

now problem is that I've to  get reset link  and place it in html template thats being set in query and that comes after html template and headers , my questions is what should be order of template , headers and form query that i may get reset link in html template  here  `$bodoymessaage= .='<a href="$link"' .....?>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273043/php-mail-problem)

Answer (score 3):

When you use `'`, the variables are not expanded. So kindly use double quotes or, use string concatenation in PHP:

```
$bodoymessaage= .='<a href="$link"' .....?>
//--------------------------^^^^^ -- This doesn't work.
```

Change the above code to either:

```
$bodoymessaage= .="<a href=\"{$link}\"" .....?>         // Use double quotes Or
$bodoymessaage= .='<a href="' . $link . '"' .....?>   // String Concatenation
```

If you see how PHP Interprets Strings:

```
$var = "Var";
'$var';    // $var
"$var";    // Var
"{$var}"   // Var
```

Comment: so will it get value that  comes after this in order?

Comment: @Sikander The main thing is the quotes buddy. Yes. Check the updated explanation.

Comment: let me try this if it helps me ,

Comment: @Sikander Yeah, please. If it works, don't forget to mark my answer. `:)`

Comment: I would mention `"{$var}"` is the best practice to replace variable in string.

Comment: doing it like this  $bodoymessaage.="<td align=\"center\"><a  href=\"{$body}\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"font-size: 16px;padding-right:20px; padding-left:20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #000; text-decoration: none; background-color: #fff; border-top: 15px solid #fff; border-bottom: 15px solid #fff; border-left: 25px solid #fff; border-right: 25px solid #fff; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; display: inline-block;\" class=\"mobile-button\">Reset Password</a></td>";

Comment: that does not even create  clickable link

Comment: @Sikander Are you sure it is `$body` and not `$link`?

Comment: @Sikander Do you wanna use `$bodoymessaage.="<td align=\"center\"><a href=\"{$link}\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"font-size: 16px;padding-right:20px; padding-left:20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #000; text-decoration: none; background-color: #fff; border-top: 15px solid #fff; border-bottom: 15px solid #fff; border-left: 25px solid #fff; border-right: 25px solid #fff; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; display: inline-block;\" class=\"mobile-button\">Reset Password</a></td>";`

Comment: yes i'm sure i mentioned link just for demoonstratin

Comment: body is the proper  word in code , this is what i've ,